# Simple .htaccess rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file. It refuses to access the following url structure:

> www.example.com/test

Even though it accesses this fine:

> www.example.com/test.php

I've ran some more complicated rewrite rules using this file and it worked just fine. For example:

> RewriteRule ^tests/([0-9]+)/?$ /tests_page.php?id=$1 [PT,L,QSA]

I don't understand how this can be happening. What am I missing here?

```
#OPTIONS
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

#ACCESS TO THE .HTACCESS FILE
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#REWRITE ENGINE
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteEngine On

#PAGES REWRITE
RewriteRule ^test/?$ /test.php
```

**Update:**

I renamed the file to tests.php and changed the rule to this and it worked:

> RewriteRule ^test/?$ /tests.php

*This still does not explain why this is happening though*.

Why can't I have the url folder name match the file name?

Comment: do you have a directory called "test"? what happens when you try to access /test?

Comment: @nomve no folder called /test/.....I get this message: Not Found

The requested URL /test was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Comment: The problem is usually I know some thing I can test. Some piece of code I can delete or something. With this, I'm at a dead-end.

Comment: Sorry I don't usually deal too much with this, so I'm also missing the finer points. A quick search here found something that might help http://serverfault.com/questions/57243/apache-mod-rewrite-fails-when-file-by-same-name-exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with `MultiViews` option. Disable it by using:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

line at the top of your .htaccess. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` module and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URI but it will serve `/file.php`.